# Path '.gitmodules' does not exist in '31627edc0c80332d93e694cb0ed379531fbc9de0'

Tags: git, mercurial, repository

I'm attempting to convert a Git repo to Mercurial using [hg convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension), but I keep running into this problem on a specific changeset:

```
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
376 Added curtain.js files.
fatal: Path '.gitmodules' does not exist in '31627edc0c80332d93e694cb0ed379531fbc9de0'
abort: cannot read submodules config file in 31627edc0c80332d93e694cb0ed379531fbc9de0
```

I haven't used any git modules, and there's never been a `.gitmodules` file as far as I know. I've tried adding the file manually before running the conversion, but it still crashes with the same message, only `Path '.gitmodules' exists on disk, but not in [...]` instead. I've been searching everywhere, but have been unable to find a solution to this problem. I did find a link to the [git converter plugin](https://mirrors.kilnhg.com/Code/Mirrors/Tools/Mercurial/Files/hgext/convert/git.py?rev=ddc7a6be2021) if it helps anyone.

Many thanks for reading.

Best regards,
dimhoLt

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is related to https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5193.

You might have some luck by specifying `--config convert.git.skipsubmodules=yes` on your command line.